# vaex filter and bin a dataframe using mask from anther series

Tags: python, dataframe, vaex

I have a large arrow file with 14 million rows. In my app I select two columns and bin them using the count/binby functionality in Vaex.

```
df.count(
  binby=axes,
  limits=limits,
  shape=(binnum,)*len(axes),
  delay=True
)
```

Some of my columns act as a mask and have either a 0 or 1. Here's an example

```
#   x    y    mask
1   1.5  4.7  0
2   0.3  2.3  1
3   2.6  9.4  1
4   5.0  3.7  0
```

I wish to bin the points in the x and y axes that only have a 1 in the mask column. How do I do this?

Comment: Would something like `df.count(..., selection="mask==1")` work?

Comment: no, this is a bug that exists and is documented [here](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/1592)

Comment: Ah sure, but in that issue there are more details than in the OP post here, related to the geo methods I suppose. Without the geo stuff, your example as state above should work i think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mask is in the same dataframe, using `selection` kwarg should work:

```py
import vaex

df = vaex.example()

df.count(binby=['x', 'y'], shape=(10,10), selection="id==0")
```